# On click get button Value

Tags: javascript

I have a button like following

```
<input type='button' value='Generate' onclick='f1()' />
```

now the f1 function should show a alert box contain button value. in this case 'Generate'

How to do this?

I tried

```
alert(this);
alert(this.val());
```

it does not work

Comment: That assumes he's using jQuery. Maybe he is, or maybe he's just confused because he saw `.val()` in some other questions.

Comment: @Barmar ya I realized that as the OP just kept javascript tag.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this.

```
<input type='button' value='Generate' onclick='f1(this)' />
```

Now alert like

```
function f1(objButton){  
    alert(objButton.value);
}
```

P.S: `val()` is actually a jQuery implementation of `value`

Answer (score 2):

Or you do this:

```
<button id='button' value='Generate' onclick='f1()'>Generate</button>
```

Then this for javascript:

```
Const click = document.getElementById('button')
Function f1{
  Alert(`${click.Value}`)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of using addEventListener() function:

```
button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let value = event.target.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container">
          <button>7</button>
          <button>8</button>
          <button>9</button>
          <button>4</button>
          <button>5</button>
          <button>6</button>
          <button>1</button>
          <button>2</button>
          <button>3</button>
          <button>0</button>
        </div>
        <p id="calc"></p>
```

---

**JS**

```
let p = document.querySelectorAll("button");
p.forEach((btn) =>
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let display = document.getElementById("calc");
    display.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
  })
);
```