# Find rowID using Javascript for editable PHP table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to create an editable table which is generated from a PHP / MySQL query.

The idea is that the query runs, the table is generated and then some cells are editable using the 'contenteditable' option.

So, I have my query (it's limited to two rows for testing purposes):-

```
$query="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE status='Received' LIMIT 2 ";
$sth = $dbLink->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();
$sql = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$num_rows = count($sql);
```

Then I have my table generated:-

```
<body>
    <div>
        <!-- start header of table -->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Repairs Received</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Customer Name</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Cust Tel</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Must Have</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Lctn</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Status</strong></td>
            </tr>


            <?php
            //loop through all results
            foreach ($sql as $row2) {
                //print out table contents 
                echo '<tr>
                <td id="rowid">'.$row2->id.'</td>
                <td>'.$row2->customer_name.'</td>
                <td>'.$row2->customer_tel.'</td>
                <td id="must" contenteditable="true">'.$row2->must_have.'</td>
                <td id="location" contenteditable="true">'.$row2->location.'</td>
                <td id="status" contenteditable="true"><select name="status1[]">
                        <option value="'.$row2->status.'">'.$row2->status.'</options>
                        <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                        <option value="Received">Received</option>
                        <option value="On Hold">On Hold</option>
                        <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
                        <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                        <option value="Dispatched">Dispatched</option>
                        <option value="Collected">Collected</option>
                        <option value="Waiting">Waiting</option>
                        </select></td>
                </tr>';
            }

            echo "</table>"; ?>
    </div>
```

Then I have my javascript (which is placed after the end of the table - I think the placing is relevant but don't know where it should go):-

```
<script>
    var must = document.getElementById("must");
    var rowid = document.getElementById("rowid").innerHTML;
    must.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        localStorage.setItem('must', this.innerHTML);
        var content = localStorage.getItem('must');
        alert(content + rowid);
    });


    </script>
</body>
```

The intention in the longer term is to have a few cells editable, and a drop down select box (that's probably a whole different question), then update the database with an AJAX call.

Until I understand how the javascript works though, I am only looking at the one cell. The above works for the first line in the test cell, and the alert (which is my testing of the variables) gives me the updated content for the cell, and the row number, however it does not if I try and edit the second row.

I've searched in multiple places however I don't want to use jquery and most of the editable table information I have found uses jquery.

I'm fine with the PHP / MySQL, it's the javascript I have yet to learn here. Any help appreciated as always. My guess is that I need to place the javascript function within the PHP foreach loop, but I have not yet found a way that works, or a way of capturing the associated row with the edited cell. Surely once the table is generated, I should be able to find the relevant row id?

Any advice gratefully received as always.

**UPDATE - 23rd November**
I've had a D'oh! moment. I didn't think about server side (PHP) and client side (Javascript) and hadn't considered that what I was trying to do was not possible in the way that I was doing it (i.e. can't set a javascript variable inside the PHP foreach loop).

I changed approach and placed a button at the end of each row and I then tried then to assign the row-id from the php to the TR tag ID and pick it up when the button is clicked, which I thought would work as the ID would be unique.

```
echo '<tr id="'.$row2->id.'">
<td><button id="save" onclick="getRow()"></button></td>
```

and the Javascript (which is in the function called by the button click):-

```
alert(document.getElementById("save").parentNode.parentNode.id);
```

This didn't work - only the first row id is reported no matter which row I click the button on.

I have also tried putting the row id onto the button and collecting that:-

```
<td class = "test-tickle"><button id="save" onclick="getRow()">'.$row2->id.'</button></td>
```

and the Javascript line:-

```
alert(document.getElementById("save").innerHTML);
```

I've tried using innerText as well but again I only get the first row.

The javascript is located just before the end body tag, but is the problem something to do with the way the table loads and when javascript runs? I was expecting that the table would have loaded before the javascript executed, thus I should be able to navigate the table?

**Update #2 23rd November - the solution**
I've solved it now. Thanks to Usman (below) for pointing me in the right direction, and then to this post:-
[On click get button Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756048/on-click-get-button-value)

The answer was to have the button onclick ="getRow(this)" and then the function was:-

```
function getRow(objButton) {
    alert(objButton.value);
}
```

I guess using 'this' calls the row that is active as opposed to the first instance from the DOM by using document.getElementById.

Now I just have to use the knowledge for the next piece of the puzzle :)

Comment: using `<td id="must">..` is setting all the `ids` same for all the rows. you must take of these cases too.

Comment: @UsmanRana - Should I be using the <tr> tag? I did try that, but couldn't get it to work either.