# How can I apply a function to multiple elements with the same class?

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

I have two (or more) buttons with the same class. I want to write a function that sets a variable to the clicked button's value, and want to apply this function to all my buttons. I've read post regarding the 'this' keyword ([such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756048/on-click-get-button-value)) but it only works if I place the `onclick` method inline which I don't want to do.

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wyPNgX)

Here is my code:

```
<button class='button' type='button' value='X'>Button 1</button>
<button class='button' type='button' value='Y'>Button 2</button>

var button = document.getElementByClass('button');
var value;

function selectValue(clicked_button) {
      value = clicked_button.value;
}

button.onclick = selectValue;
```

Also, I am not sure but do I need to use a loop to apply the function to every button? Such as:

```
 for(var i = 0; i <= button.length; i++) {
  button[i].onclick = selectValue; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your code:

- There is no `getElementByClass` function. I don't know how your code runs. It's called `getElementsByClassName`.
- The `getElementsByClassName` returns a array of elements (2 in your example), so you'll have to loop through it and add the `onclick` event.
- To access the current button inside the `onclick` event handler, use `this`. You cannot pass whatever parameters you want to the function because its signature is fixed. It gets passed a reference to the event itself, not the clicked element, so the name `clicked_button` is deceiving. We usually call that parameter `event`, or `e` for short. You can access the element using `event.target`, but using `this` is just easier.

Try this (I added the `console.log` line just for demo, but you don't need it):

```js
var value;
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].onclick = selectValue;
}

function selectValue() {
  value = this.value;
  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<button class='button' type='button' value='X'>Button 1</button>
<button class='button' type='button' value='Y'>Button 2</button>
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly. Sorry about elementsByClassName I wrote my codepen a little too fast and I'm still beginning.

The only thing still confusing me is the THIS concept. Basically, this refer to what is being clicked. correct?

Comment: `this` depends on the context. In the context of an event handler it refers to the element that raised the event. So in your example, yes it refers to the button that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll("button")
    .forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", e => selectValue(btn)));
```

Answer (score 1):

- The function `getElementByClass` doesn't exist, use `querySelector` instead.
- Loop over your button elements and add the onclick event.

**Recommendation:** Use `addEventListener` instead.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
var value;

function selectValue() {
  value = this.value;
  console.log(value);
}

for (btn of buttons)
  btn.onclick = selectValue;
```

```css
button {
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<button class='button' type='button' value='X'>Button 1</button>
<button class='button' type='button' value='Y'>Button 2</button>
```

## Resources

- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Is the OP code correct if he uses `getElementsByClassName()` ?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui no, the OP needs to loop over button elements

Comment: Thanks for your help, this also work as intended. Should querySelector be prioritize over getElementsByClassName ?

Comment: @oehaut you can use both :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use loop over HTMLCollection `buttons`

```
function selectValue(event) {
  value = event.target.value;
}
var button = document. getElementsByClassName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].onclick = selectValue;
}
```

Comment: Would you just edit your answer with anything, just I can't delete my downvote unless you edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

If using jquery, you use either of the following without looping.

1. This will set value to the clicked button

   var valueToSet = 'XX';
   $(document).on('click', '.button', function () {
           $(this).val(valueToSet);
   });
2. This will set same value for every element with class name button

   var valueToSet = 'XX';
       $(document).on('click', '.button', function () {
              $('.button').val(valueToSet);
       });
3. Use this in a case where there are other elements with class name button other than the buttons

   var valueToSet = 'XX';
       $("button.button").click(function(){
          if($(this).attr("class") == 'button'){
              $('button.button').val(valueToSet);
          }
       });