# Why does element in onClick refer to inner image tag instead of button tag?

Tags: javascript, html, image, button, onclick

I've been working on a React web app that has a button with an image inside of it:

```
<button
  value="same"
  onClick={e => this.onClick(e.target.value)}
>
  <img
    src={image}
    alt=""
  />
  <h3>Same</h3>
</button>
```

This is the corresponding `onClick` function:

`onClick = value => { console.log("onClick value = ", value)};`

For some reason, the `value` is `undefined`. When I print `e.target` instead, I get the `img` tag. I'm using this same function for another button, so I don't always know that the value is `"same"` when the function is run. I'm not sure why `e.target` refers to the `img` tag. I know you can also give the button a background, but I would like to avoid that because I have a specific class that needs to be applied to `img`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Lok at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756048/on-click-get-button-value

Comment: `<button>` is not supposed to have children, like `<h3>`

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Thank you for the comment, do you have a link I could look at to better understand why. And is there a way to style an image inside of a button if I use the button `background` style? Or should I just scratch the whole button and use `onClick` on an `img`?