# Can the <button> 'value' attribute be a number?

Tags: javascript, html, button

Example:

```
<button type="button" value="5">5</button>
```

What I'm trying to do is create a javascript calculator. When the button is pushed, I would like to be able to display that value. Currently, I cannot seem to figure out how to retrieve the value and am unsure if it's valid to use a number.

Comment: So many ways to solve it without attributes. Here's one: https://jsfiddle.net/c29g0ud6/2/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On click get button Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756048/on-click-get-button-value)

Comment: That question's answers show how to get the value of the button. Anything that is valid in an attribute value, is valid in the `value` attribute's value.

Comment: A HTML attribute is always a string. Of course you can store a numeric one.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, it answers part of the question, but doesn't speak to whether value can be an integer.

Comment: As I said in my comment, you can set the value to any value an attribute is settable to. There's no need to answer that part of the question; a simple perusal of, say, [MDN's documentation of the attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) will confirm what I and others have said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it would be most appropriate to use the `data` attribute ..  Like so:

```
 <button type="button" data-value="5">5</button>
```

Then you can retrieve it simply using :

```
var el = document.querySelector('your_button');
console.log(el.getAttribute('data-value'));
```

**NOTE** That I am using `querySelector` as a generic term ..   You could give it a `class`, `name` or `ID` --  And retrieve it IE `getElementById()`

Answer (score 1):

According to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

> value: text

This means "value" attribute always receives a text (string).

You can always [parse the number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133814/10473393) if in need.

i.e.

```
// having myButtonValue as the value from button
var number = +myButtonValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `input` instead:

```html
<input id="b5" type="button" value="5" />
```

you can then parse the value into a number:

```js
const value = document.getElementById("b5").value;
```

Answer (score -2):

Any component can have any attribute, but the button for selecting integers values may not be the most HTML semantically correct.

Comment: HTML defines rules about what attributes are valid on which elements.